# how can refresh the fragment when I finish the Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

how can refresh the fragment when I finish the Activity?

When I from MapFragment to open PostActivity, then I am writing finish and submit the post and use finish(); function to close PostActivity, how can refresh the Mapfragment?

in my MapFragment code

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Post.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and this is my Post code

```
private void uploadImage(){
        String userID = getID;
        String image = convertToString();
        String image2 = convertToString2();
        String title = maptitle.getText().toString();
        String info = mapInfo.getText().toString();
        String lat = currentlat.getText().toString();
        String lng = currentlng.getText().toString();
        String address = currentAddress.getText().toString();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MapSendPost> call = apiInterface.mapSendPost(image,userID,image2,title,info,lat,lng,address);

        progressDialog.show();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MapSendPost>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MapSendPost> call, Response<MapSendPost> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                MapSendPost img_pojo = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(MapPost.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MapSendPost> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Server Response",""+t.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

or when I finish the Activity, how can call on the fragment loadMap(); ?

and in my MapFragment, I have add this code

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        initMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadMaps();
    }
```

but, it's still not working...

Comment: after closing finishing activity you want to refresh your map fragment?

Comment: yes. please check the video. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P7blrIsQ6frJ5dZL8_SbqjBvvMkajQS2/view
when I post the info and submit it, how can auto show the marker?